# Issue using Pythons Mechanize to extract data from website

Tags: python, parsing, session-cookies, mechanize, user-agent

So Im trying to extract some data off a football stats website to create my own fantasy football rankings this year.  I am having success using mechanize to fill out the the authentication form and enter the website.  However when I read in the page, the data that shows up on the website is not there and I know the authentication worked.  For example, if I view the pages source code, all the data is there... but when I "login" through mechanize and read in the page, the area with the data is simply empty..

To be more specific, I want to target the players, extract/open their specific stats page by iterating over the "side bar container" located in the url in the code below...

However then mechanize reads in the data and returns it the whole "side bar container" is empty.

My code code is posted below:

```
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Firefox')]
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.open("https://www.profootballfocus.com/sample/by_player.php?tab=by_player&season=2008&surn=B&playerid=&group=")
br.select_form('login')
br.form['amember_login'] = 'insert your username'
br.form['amember_pass'] = 'insert your password'
response = br.submit()
print response.read()
```

The website is www.profootballfocus.com.  In this example, I created an account to try and scrape the free sample data from 2008 (the url in the code has the direct url I am trying to target).  Any help or pointers is appreciated! Thanks

Comment: I tried the same code. It returned an webpage with invalid username or password error.

Comment: Thanks for trying thavan, did you create a username and password for the web page and it threw you the error?

Comment: Probably no body will make a special account for the case. I think the sidebar is just loaded after the page. In the good case is loaded via Ajax and javascript. In the bad is Flash. Just open the site with firebug or whatever tool you use and check for the XHR requests, you might find the needed data in there.